# Why does angular-socket-io complain with 'Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400?'

Tags: angularjs, sockets

I have a node application (angular-fullstack) that I moved from http to https.  Everything is working, but the socket connection isn't.  What am I missing?

In the socketFactory I have:

```
var ioSocket = io('https://localhost', {
  path: '/socket.io-client'
});
```

which I believe already causes the transport to use 'wss://'.  The https connection is all good. For a time, I believed that somehow nginx was not handling the proxy correctly.  However that was incorrect.

Next, I changed form 'https://locahost' to 'https://xxx_actual_server_url_xxxx' and now everything works properly after the initial page reload.  HOWEVER I do see ONE:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx_actual_server_url_xxxx/
socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Y4_cKvyTERz_F1ZCAAAK' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

What could be causing this? and How to get around it?  I am not doing any load balancing or anything and just running the development server with 'grunt serve'.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching and hunting, I discovered that when using sockets with nginx I needed to add the following to my proxy stuff:

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Having done that, all is now good.  Hopefully this will help someone else.
The full set of parameters for forwarding the proxy with nginx is:

```
 location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $host;
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

Thanks to those that looked at this!